# How to calculate the 'Daylight Factor' of a room?

Tags: lighting

I am a faculty in a public school. Our school has to submit an infrastructure report to the funding agency. One of the questions asked is to calculate the 'Daylight Factor' in each classroom.

I have done some research online and I have come up with the following formula:
$$DF=\frac{E_i}{E_0}\times 100$$
Where $E_i$ is the illuminance on an indoor working plane and $E_0$ is the illuminance on an outdoor plane (un-obstructed from sunlight).

Is this a good approach? I have seen other formulae which involve the ratio of 'Total window area' to 'Floor area'

Kindly suggest a good approach.

Comment: The approach accepted by the Funding Agency - have you asked them or checked the website or faq?